# Kotlin toFloat function round-off problem

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion

One of the library is accepting only float value, so i am trying to convert integer value to float value in kotlin using toFloat() function. But it is giving nearest value and not the exact value. Official documentation also says

> Returns the value of this number as a Float, which may involve rounding.

I am trying to convert 105312355 to Float, which is giving me 1.05312352E8. If i reverse calculate float to integer it is giving me 105312352.

So, how do i force to calculate correct value.

Comment: There _is_ no float exactly equal to 105312355.  You _can't_ get the exact value back.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of [Floating Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is that it can express a wider range of values at the expense of precision compared to the same size of Int.

Only a Double (rather than Float) can preserve the full precision of the Int. Something will need to give.